# How can I add a new editable textfield row in a table in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

How can I add a new editable text-field row in a table in react?
Whenever I add click on add button it just adds a new table row which is not editable by default. The logic is defined inside the add addNewUserHandler which should add the new text field row instead it just adds non-editable table-row.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Table } from "@material-ui/core";
import { Paper } from "@material-ui/core";
import {
  TableHead,
  TableBody,
  TableCell,
  TableRow,
  Button,
  makeStyles,
  Icon,
  Tooltip,
  TextField
} from "@material-ui/core";
import InputBase from "@material-ui/core/InputBase";
import DeleteIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Delete";
import AddIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Add";
import CheckIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Check";
import Fab from "@material-ui/core/Fab";
import SearchIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Search";
import CloseIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Close";
import EditIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Edit";


const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    width: "100%"
  },
  paper: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(3),
    width: "100%",
    overflowX: "auto",
    marginBottom: theme.spacing(2)
  },
  table: {
    minWidth: 650
  }
}));

const Userdata = () => {
  const [data, setdata] = useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Frozen yoghurt",
      calories: 159,
      fat: 6.0,
      carbs: 24,
      protein: 4.0,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Ice cream sandwich",
      calories: 237,
      fat: 9.0,
      carbs: 37,
      protein: 4.3,
      
    },
    { id: 3, name: "Eclair", calories: 300, fat: 7.0, carbs: 67, protein: 4 },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: "Velvet cake",
      calories: 237,
      fat: 2.5,
      carbs: 17,
      protein: 3,
    }
  ]);

 
  const [editingIndex, setEditingIndex] = useState(-1);



  const addNewUserHandler = () => {
    let newData = [{
      id: "",
      name: "",
      calories: "",
      fat: "",
      carbs: "",
      protein: ""
    }];
    const Data = data;
    console.log(newData)
    setdata([...Data, newData])
 
  };

  const addNewData = e => {
    console.log(e);
  };

  const startEditing = i => {
    setEditingIndex(i);
  };

  const stopEditing = () => {
    setEditingIndex(-1);
  };

  const inputChangeHandler = (e, i) => {
    let result = data.map((data) =>{
     return data.id === i ? {...data, [e.target.name]:e.target.value} : {...data}
    })
     setdata(result)
  
  }

  const submitInputHandler = () => {
    setEditingIndex(-1);
  };

  const deleteRowHandler = id => {
    const temp = [...data];
    const filteredData = temp.filter(data => data.id !== id);
    setdata([...filteredData,]);
  };

  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Paper className={classes.paper}>
        <Table className={classes.table} size="small">
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
              <TableCell>Id.</TableCell>
              <TableCell>Dessert (100g serving)</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">Calories</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">Fat&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">Carbs&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">Protein&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">
                <InputBase
                  placeholder="search"
                  inputProps={{ "aria-label": "search" }}
                  style={{ verticalAlign: "middle" }}
                />
                <SearchIcon style={{ verticalAlign: "middle" }} />
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">
                <Tooltip title="Add data" aria-label="add">
                  <Fab
                    color="primary"
                    className={classes.fab}
                    onClick={addNewUserHandler}
                  >
                    <AddIcon />
                  </Fab>
                </Tooltip>
              </TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>

          <TableBody>
            {data.map((data, id) => (
              <TableRow key={id}>
                  {editingIndex === data.id ? (
                <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                    <TextField
                      style={{ width: "3rem" }}
                      name="id"
                      onChange={(e) =>inputChangeHandler(e, data.id)}
                      value={id+1}
                    />
                    </TableCell>
                  ) : 
                  (
                  <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                   {id+1}
                </TableCell>
                
                  )}
                  {editingIndex === data.id ? (
                    <TableCell>
                      <TextField
                    style={{ width: "8rem" }}
                    onChange={(e) =>inputChangeHandler(e, data.id)}
                    name="name"
                    value={data.name}
                    />
                    </TableCell>
                    
                  ) : (
                  <TableCell style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                    {data.name}
                </TableCell>
                  )}
                  {editingIndex === data.id ? (
                <TableCell align="center">
                    <TextField
                      style={{ width: "8rem" }}
                      onChange={(e) =>inputChangeHandler(e, data.id)}
                      name="calories"
                      value={data.calories}
                      />
                      </TableCell>
                  ) : (
                    <TableCell style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                      {data.calories}
                    </TableCell>
                  )}
                {editingIndex === data.id ? (
                <TableCell>
                  <TextField
                    style={{ width: "8rem" }}
                    onChange={(e) =>inputChangeHandler(e, data.id)}
                    name="fat"
                    value={data.fat}
                  />
              </TableCell>
                ) : (
                  <TableCell style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                    {data.fat}
                  </TableCell>
                )}
                  {editingIndex === data.id ? (
                <TableCell align="center">
                    <TextField
                      style={{ width: "8rem" }}
                      onChange={(e) =>inputChangeHandler(e, data.id)}
                      name="carbs"
                      value={data.carbs}
                    />
                </TableCell>
                  ) : (
                    <TableCell style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                      {data.carbs}
                    </TableCell>
                  )}
                  {editingIndex === data.id ? (
                <TableCell align="center">
                    <TextField
                    disabled={false}
                      style={{ width: "8rem" }}
                      onChange={(e) =>inputChangeHandler(e, data.id)}
                      name="protein"
                      value={data.protein}
                    />
                </TableCell>
                  ) : (
                    <TableCell style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                    {data.protein}
                    </TableCell>
                  )}
                <TableCell style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                  {editingIndex !== data.id ? (
                    <EditIcon onClick={() => startEditing(data.id)} style= {{cursor: "pointer"}}/>
                  ) : (
                    <CheckIcon onClick={submitInputHandler} style= {{cursor: "pointer"}} />
                  )}
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell>
                  {editingIndex !== data.id ? (
                    <DeleteIcon onClick={() => deleteRowHandler(data.id)} style= {{cursor: "pointer"}}/>
                  ) : (
                    <CloseIcon onClick={stopEditing} style= {{cursor: "pointer"}} />
                  )}
                </TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            ))}
            {/* <TableRow>
              <TablePagination
                count={rows.length}
                rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
                page={page}
                onChangePage={handleChangePage}
              />
            </TableRow> */}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </Paper>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Userdata;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lsc4t.png)

Comment: please do not post this long code, just post the main part, things like css and stuff should only be added here if its really really important for the issue, this will save us all loads of time, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I'm getting your point right, but if what you need is for the row to be editable when adding new data, then here's what you should be doing:

First of all, for your `newData`, give a unique `id`, you can use `uuid` for that, or `Math.random` if you're not building a real application.
Then call `startEditing(newData.id)` inside your `addNewUserHandler`, as in:

```
const addNewUserHandler = () => {
    let newData = [
      {
        id: Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9999),
        name: "",
        calories: "",
        fat: "",
        carbs: "",
        protein: ""
      }
    ];
    const Data = data;
    startEditing(newData.id)
    setdata([...Data, newData]);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with newData in addNewUserHandler as below:

```
let newData = {
      id: "",
      name: "",
      calories: "",
      fat: "",
      carbs: "",
      protein: ""
    };
```